# concurrent configuration PostgreSQL and tomcat

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling

Postgresql has a default of 100 regarding max_connections.
Tomcat pooling has a default of 100 regarding maxActive and maxIdle.

How about configuring data sources in context.xml for Apps in Tomcat?

Given: 3 apps (war) containing 3 datasources in their context.xml
Do I have to set maxActive and maxIdle to 33 for the three datasources to meet PostgreSQL's default of max_connections = 100?

I guess yes, because in `pg_stat_activity` I've seen that "maxIdle" in Tomcat leads to establish "maxIdle" connections in PostgreSQL.

> **Note:** Using Tomcat 8.5.x and PostgreSQL 9.6.x

Comment: Did you set connection pooling?

Comment: Yes, I've written "Tomcat pooling".